# Spring Testing Context Autowired

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Sorry for the silly question, but i can't find out why this code is not working with Spring.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class DBDumpTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource source;

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDump() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(source); //OK
        Assert.assertNotNull(new DBDump().getDatasource()); //NULL NOT OK
    }
}
```

With Class:

```
public class DBDump {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBDump.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;


    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

So why does new DBDump().getDatasource() not return the Mocked Instance, while in the Test-Class the @Autowired Annotation seems to work?

Comment: I think there is no need to mock datasource while you start the whole spring context. Anyway, you have to tell us what exactly is not working.

Comment: i expect the new DBDump().getDatasource() not to be null but  being injected via @Autowired from the ContextConfiguration.  DataSource is just an example class it could be any other bean.

Comment: Why should a freshly created instance outside the scope of Spring (the `new DBDump()`) be injected by Spring...